# Operator overloading problems?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

i had seven errors in this code containing operator overloading problems , i try to do operator overloading on >> and << and it doesn't work

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
private:
    double re,im;
public:
    complex(double a=0.0,double b=0.0)
    {re=a;im=b;}
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,complex&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,complex&);
};
istream& operator>>(istream& s,complex& cc2)
{
    cout<<"Enter real part:";
    s>>cc2.re;
    cout<<"Enter imaginary part:";
    s>>cc2.im;
    return s;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& t,complex& cc2)
{
    t<<"The real part="<<cc2.re<<endl;
    t<<"The imaginary part="<<cc2.im<<endl;
    return t;
}
int main()
{
    complex c1,c2(2.4,3.8);
    cin>>c1;
    cout<<c1;
    cout<<c2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What **are** the errors? Most of us can't compile code in our heads. Also, you should edit your question to add relevant language tags.

Comment: Remove the abominable `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working here with on GNU/Linux with `g++ 4.9.2`, `clang++-4.7` and `clang++-4.6`. Seems to be a compiler bug.

You can try to update to a more recent version of VC++.

Comment: i don't know , i am using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 since 3 months and i don't have any problems

Comment: Not sure 100% if it's a compiler bug, it might be that both gcc and clang are doing something wrong, but sincerely, quite recent versions of gcc and clang doing it fine, and VC++6 launched on 1998 makes me think gcc and clang wins.

Comment: any suggestions to another compiler ?

Comment: Yes, you can use clang or gcc. If you're using windows, you can also get more recent versions of VisualStudio/VisualC++, I'm sure you can use them for free.

Comment: @AhmedSamaligui As alesegdia said, you are using a 17-year-old compiler. Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is completely free and comparable to the professional versions of previous editions. I recommend upgrading to a newer more-standards-compliant and bug-free compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me "as is". Not sure which platform you're using, but since this is C++ code, make sure you're using the compiler for  **C++** instead of **C**.

This is the output from my GNU/Linux terminal (placed the code in file `test.cpp`):

```
➜  /tmp  g++ test.cpp -o test
➜  /tmp  ./test
Enter real part:4
Enter imaginary part:5
The real part=4
The imaginary part=5
The real part=2.4
The imaginary part=3.8
```

Worked without changes.

Comment: i am using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0  and i had errors

Comment: @AhmedSamaligui: You're using a very old version of the compiler. You should find a more recent version to avoid compiler bugs that have been solved already.